# Unable to close or Esc from Pending Flag Popup

Tags: bug, review-queues, flags, user-interface

I got in a situation that while I'm reviewing a answer for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/19030819), it do not look like an answer. So I click the flag option to flag the answer & suddenly **all got stuck**. I have also pressed the close button on top of popup & Esc button, both didn't worked. I have added the link & screenshot.
[image]

The issue I have faced in `Firefox 58.0.2 (32-bit) - Firefox Quantum`
OS - `Linux Mint`

Comment: No repro on Chrome/Win10. Please add your browser and OS.

Comment: Edited my question & added browser details

Comment: If this happens again, could you please check if there are any errors logged in the browser console (press F12 and select the "Console" tab if it's not already open)?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Sure... i will do that.

Comment: No repro in `Firefox 58.0.2 (32-bit) - Firefox Quantum` also.

Comment: Wait 6 to 8 weeks for it to self-dismiss.